# Dice game adding random die totals together to a variable

Tags: python, dice

I'm trying to code a dice game where each roll it adds the two die totals together to a variable, and does this each iteration of the roll function, so in the end there's a combined total of each roll.

I've already tried creating a separate function to add the values but I've had no success.

This is my roll function:

```py
def roll():
   global die1
   global die2
   global dietotal
   global diewholetotal

   die1 = random.randint(1,6)
   die2 = random.randint(1,6)
   dietotal = (die1 + die2)
```

This is the whole dice game:

```py
def dicegame():
   truroll = input("Roll the dice? ")
   if truroll == "Yes" or "yes" or "y" or "Y":
      roll()
      print("The rolls were:", die1, " and " ,die2, " and the total was: ", dietotal)
      sprint("Rolling again...")
      time.sleep(1)
      # adding the roll to the total
      print("The rolls were:", die1, " and " ,die2, " and the total was: ", dietotal)
      sprint("Rolling again...")
      # adding the roll to the total
      time.sleep(1)
      print("The rolls were:", die1, " and " ,die2, " and the total was: ", dietotal)
      sprint("Rolling again...")
      addnum(x)
      time.sleep(1)
      # adding the roll to the total
      print("The rolls were:", die1, " and " ,die2, " and the total was: ", dietotal)
      sprint("Rolling again...")
      addnum(x)
      time.sleep(1)
      # adding the roll to the total
      print("The rolls were:", die1, " and " ,die2, " and the total was: ", dietotal)
      sprint("Rolling again...")
      # adding the roll to the total
      time.sleep(1)
      print("The total for these rolls was: ", x)
      print(#here would be the total for all the rolls added)

   else:
      print("Returning to games list...")
      gamelist()
```

I didn't really expect my version to work, so I replaced it with comments. I hope you can help

Comment: Suggestion: define a 'dice" [class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) that has a "roll()" method.  Your game will create two "dice" objects, and "roll()" them as needed.  Here is one (of many!) tutorials: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-construct-classes-and-define-objects-in-python-3

Comment: what is "not working"? and whats in the `addnum`

Comment: the addnum was my attempt at creating a function that adds the dietotal to a separate variable, seen here ```python def addnum(score):
   score + dietotal```

Comment: @benll6yd: I'd strongly urge you to try "classes", and see where that gets you.  Please refer to the two links I cited - they should point you in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you @paulsm4, I'm reading the classes one right now and it seems very helpful, much appreciated